# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow List Item not updated

Tags: tasks

I have a List and a Task List.

In my List i have created a column "Reason for Rejection."

In my Task List i have created a custom column "Reason for Rejection."

in my workflow if the approver, rejects a request and fill up the Reason for Rejection column in the Task List. This should update the Column in the Reason for Rejection in my List in the form submitted. But it's not working. can anyone help me?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You will need to at the very least provide some screenshots of the workflow designer.

Comment: Thanks sir i editted with screenshots.

Comment: In the 'Find the List Item' part you need to clarify which Item should be retrieved from All Tasks. For example Task Item where field ID eq value 11